# Getting Pylint E1101 - Instance has no such member

Tags: python, pylint

Pylint doesn't like this code:

```
class sequence(list):
    def __init__(self, n):
        list.__init__(self)
        self += self._generate_collatz_seq(n)
        self.pivots = self._generate_pivots()
        self.data = self._make_data()

    def _collatz_function(self, n):
        if n % 2 == 0:
            return(int(n/2))
        else:
            return(3*n + 1)

    def _generate_collatz_seq(self, x):
        int(x)
        sequence_holder = []
        while x != 1:
            sequence_holder.append(x)
            x = self._collatz_function(x)
        sequence_holder.append(1)
        return sequence_holder

    def _generate_pivots(self):
        pivots_holder = []
        for element in self:
            if element % 2 != 0:
                pivots_holder.append(element)
        return pivots_holder


    def _make_data(self):
        data_holder = []
        data_holder.append(len(self))
        data_holder.append(len(self.pivots))
        return data_holder
```

It says

> E1101: Instance of 'sequence' has no 'pivots' member(56,36)

This is before I have made any instances of sequence. I'm sure I haven't gone about my task in the most efficient way, but I can't see that I've done anything wrong.

Comment: Also, `list.__init__(self)` is not the correct way to call the parent constructor. Do `super().__init__(n)` instead.

Comment: @ErikCederstrand Fixed - the indentation issues aren't in my original code, they were introduced by copy-paste. I thought you only need to use super() when your class is inheriting from multiple other classes?

Comment: It may work but it's definitely not recommended and certainly surprising for most readers.

Comment: Oh ok. Well I guess I'll change if it brings my code closer to standard convention, but I'm a little uneasy about it mostly because I don't understand how it works. I read about MRO etc. for multiple inheritance but I don't get why, for example, super().__init()__  would take only n as an argument where list.__init()__ took arguments (self, n).

Comment: That's because `list.__init__(self, n)` calls `__init__` as a class method while you should really be calling it as an instance method (i.e. `super().__init__(n)`). Your code works anyway, but it's ugly.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. I haven't been programming long enough to be aesthetically discriminating, but I'll take your word for it. Thanks for the advice.